# Inline SVG background not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, svg, internet-explorer-11, inline-svg

I have the following inline SVG defined as a background-image in my css.

```
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 10 10'> <path d='M2 10 L8 0 L10 0 L10 10' fill='%238A92DF'></path></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

It works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Edge, but fails in Internet Explorer 11. Why?

[JSfiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/ar734h07/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to full URL encode your svg.

If you're using VSCode, there is a extension called "URL Encode" that'll do this for you... OR you can easily find one online: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Note that I've also removed the "version" attribute and the ";charset=utf8" part, not sure if needed, but to clear things up...

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2010%2010'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M2%2010%20L8%200%20L10%200%20L10%2010'%20fill%3D'%238A92DF'%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: You come late to the party, but still it's very appreciated. Now I'll be one step closer to full IE11 support in my webapp.

Comment: I know :) I was searching on google and this was the first link, so I answered, for anyone that may end here....

Comment: The combination of URL encoding and removing ;charset=utf8 worked for me.

Comment: The removal of `utf8` is essential to make this work. The answer should be updated to make that clear. I already had the URL encoding so it was that only thing left for me to try. But I can imagine others dismissing it as inconsequential.